# "Обробити" чи "Опрацювати" заявку?

Tags: різниця-між-словами

"Обробити" чи "Опрацювати" заявку користувача?

Answer (score 2):

Спираюсь на такі матеріали:

- [Стаття «Обробіток, обробка, оброблення, опрацювання» в циклі «Уроки державної мови» з газети «Хрещатик»](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53406/26051.html).
- [Стаття «Опрацювання — оброблення» Л. В. Туровської](https://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/51182/24-Turovska.pdf#page=2) в розділі «Консультації» в [«Термінологічному віснику» 2011 року, випуск 1](http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/handle/123456789/51133).

Згідно з обома статтями, *обробляти*/*оброблення* — це коли ми змінюємо щось, доводячи його до потрібного стану. А значення «глибоко вивчити / докладно ознайомитися» лишається для слів *опрацювати*/*опрацювання*. Із цього виходить, що організація/система зазвичай *опрацьовує* заявку користувача. *Оброблення* заявки означало б процес внесення якихось змін до неї, як-от обробка пісні чи обробка перекладу, наприклад виправлення орфографічних помилок у заявці, але таке вкрай рідко роблять для заявок.

Згідно з другою статтею, вибір слова також визначається галуззю (наприклад, у бібліотечно-біографічній справі перевагу надають термінові опрацювання). Наскільки я розумію, набір значень слова *опрацювати* загалом ширший за набір значень слова *обробити*: *оброблення* передбачає внесення змін, а *опрацювання* може означати як абстрактніші речі, так і власне *оброблення*.

Висновок: організація/система зазвичай *опрацьовує* заявку користувача.